# how can i make my own map in iPhone ( not using google map)

Tags: iphone

i've got the trouble when developing iPhone apps.
i want to make my own mapkit, (include annotation, title, and subtitle) with my own map too, i mean without using google map, i have my own map.
it's possible to doing like that.???
if yes, how it could be.??
please someone explain about it, i've been confused with that task.. :(
thnx before.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Route-Me library - http://code.google.com/p/route-me/ - it's free to use and open source so if you want to get involved in development it's a good place to start.

Comment: thanx guys,, nice info..
i'll learn every code at there..
but i've got the trouble when i try to build and run MapView, when built is finishm it says : "No launchable executable present at path."
i've already download all documents in link that you suggest.
why it happen.??